# Error: Unexpected "<" in vite react in JS files

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am making a react app with **vite** instead of **creat react app**. When I use **.jsx** as suffix, it works fine. But when I use **.js**, throws hundreds of errors in my files, such as:

```
Layout.js:131:9: error: Unexpected "<"
```

I've read this in [twitter](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1362050255009816577) from [Evan You](https://github.com/yyx990803) but is there no way?
As far as I used this code in **vite.config.ts** file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(() => ({
    esbuild: {
        loader: 'jsx',
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
          loader: {
            '.js': 'jsx',
          },
        },
    },
})
```

but it still didn't work! Could you possibly help me?

Comment: As you pointed out in that tweet, Vite by design does not process JSX from `.js` files. If your file has JSX, it should use the `.jsx` extension.

Comment: Did you got solution for this ?

Comment: No, I didn't succeed, I'd rather continue with TSX `@Phanindra`

Answer (score 8):

Try the below Vite configuration. This configuration worked for me. But in every js file, need to import React.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import fs from 'fs/promises';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
    },
    esbuild: {
        loader: 'jsx',
        include: /src\/.*\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [],
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            plugins: [
                {
                    name: 'load-js-files-as-jsx',
                    setup(build) {
                        build.onLoad(
                            { filter: /src\\.*\.js$/ },
                            async (args) => ({
                                loader: 'jsx',
                                contents: await fs.readFile(args.path, 'utf8'),
                            })
                        );
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    plugins: [react()],
});
```