# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at constants.js? using react + vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, vite

i want to show the button in the sidebar with name and a icon. i was looping through the categories. categories was imported from the constants.js file from the utils folder. but instead of that it is showing the following error below. when i commented the code of categories array part everything works fine. installed react with vite

```
constants.js?t=1675529881066:18 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at constants.js?t=1675529881066:18:24)
```

**constants.js file**

```
import MusicNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MusicNote';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import CodeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Code';
```

categories array

```
export const categories = [
  { name: 'New', icon: <HomeIcon /> },
  { name: 'JS Mastery', icon: <CodeIcon /> },
  { name: 'Music', icon: <MusicNoteIcon /> },
];
```

**mapping through the categories in Sidebar.jsx component**

```
{categories.map((category) => (
    <button>
        <span>{category.icon}</span>
        <span>{category.name}</span>
    </button>
))}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have JSX in a non .jsx file, maybe it’s categories

Comment: okay how to fix it

Comment: Search exactly what the comment said: you have JSX in a non .jsx file (if you search exactly that in google, you'll learn what is happening). Minimal effort is required here before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your `vite` project is not configured to process `jsx` in `constants.js` file. Try changing file name to `constants.jsx`.

**Edit:**

Rather than changing the extension from `js` to `jsx`, you could add this configuration for `vite` to process `jsx` in a `js` file here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71945129/8339172

Comment: Please inspect your page and code. Probably some CSS issue, or you might be rendering things conditionally.